Why concmath-otf in TeXlive2023 with smaller \oiint symbol but fine in TeXlive2024?
Use the concmath-otf package, I found a smaller \oiint in TeXLive2023 but normal in TeXLive2024. I wonder what's the reason? And is there anywhere report this related problem?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[Style={upint}]{concmath-otf}
\begin{document}
    
    \[
    \int_a^b{f\left( x \right) \text{d}x}=f\left( \xi \right) \left( b-a \right) 
    \]
    
    \[
    \oiint{f\left( x \right) \text{d}x\text{d}y}
    \]
\end{document}





unrelated, but Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

Can't reproduce with tl23, but if it is back to normal in tl24, what problem do you want to report?

I know the advantage of \[ and \], and I will change it, the code above is just with bad-habit. Thanks yr advice.

I have implemented the running result on Overleaf with xelatex on tl2023, it's actually strange that u can't reproduce?

I have a fully updated tl23, not the frozen spring version from overleaf. But anyway: what problem do you want to report?

sorry, I think the small proportion of oinnt instead of int is obviously smaller(in contrast to the first equation). I have edited it the result with tl2024.

If it works fine in tl24, the problem seems to have been fixed. What exactly do you want to report?

Umm, I just wonder what cause the smaller oiint with the frozen spring version in tl2023, is that anywhere reported the related infomation? I know that I can fix it by updating the package or the tl version. Thanks.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am not sure if a question ask for the reason or related issues with the older package NOT worked but the newer version worked is proper here. It's for my first time to do that, if that's improper, I apologize for it. Since it has been fixed, there is actually no need to know where to know or why. Aha~

I can't reproduce with any of TL 2022, 2023 or 2024. looking at the package histories, I would guess the font changed. usually problems which are due to outdated software get closed for that reason. a question about why isn't clearly in that category, but it isn't clear what kind of answer you want. if I could reproduce, I could compare the fonts, but would that be useful? knowing why something changed can be generally useful, but does that apply here? there may never have been a report or it may have been an email to the font designer.

@cfr I can't agree u more,but I actually reproduce it with tl2023(the forzen spring version)  And now I wonder in this case should I just delete this question?

I can't remember for sure, but it looks like the link from inline upright \oiint to its displayed variant was missing in the Math table. It's just a bug fix that happened between 2023 and 2024.

@DanielFlipo Thanks you for designing such elegant font, and your kind paraphase.
